# relabel_configs - drop specific metrics that have specific values for a label

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a metric istio_requests_total

I want to drop all the data from`istio_requests_total`, which have specific label values like

```
istio_requests_total {reporter="source"}
```

I have tried metric relabel configs, but they apply to all metrics and not just **istio_requests_total**

```
  metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [reporter]
    regex: '^source$'
    action: drop
```

Answer (score 5):

The following relabeling config must drop metrics matching the `istio_requests_total{reporter="source"}` [series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors):

```yaml
metric_relabel_configs:
- source_labels: [__name__, reporter]
  regex: 'istio_requests_total;source'
  action: drop
```

This relabeling rule works in the following way per each scraped metric:

1. It joins the metric name with the `reporter` label value. It uses `;` separator for joining. The default separator can be changed if needed via `separator` option in the relabel config.
2. It matches the result from step 1 against the provided `regex`. The regex is automatically anchored to the beginning and the end of the matching string, so there is no need in specifying `^` and `$` anchors in the `regex`.
3. If the `regex` matches the result from step 1, then the metric is dropped. Otherwise it isn't dropped.

P.S. I work on a Prometheus-like monitoring solution - VictoriaMetrics, which provides [some improvements](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html#relabeling-enhancements) over Prometheus relabeling. These improvements can simplify some relabeling tasks as this one. For example, the following VictoriaMetrics-specific relabeling rule is equivalent to the rule above, but it looks more clear:

```yaml
metric_relabel_configs:
- if: 'istio_requests_total{reporter="source"}'
  action: drop
```